# How do I include two versions of jquery on a single page ( one of them is minified )

Tags: jquery

I am using this code

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.1.3 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_1_3 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 1.3.2 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_3_2 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

but the above is for two uncompressed versions .

My page has one umcompressed(1.7.1) and one minified version (1.8.1.min)

how do I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly the same way, compression has no impact on this.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_8_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script> <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

Comment: @user1749105: That's correct, you must have the paths or filenames wrong. Agaih, compression has no effect on this.